# Laravel 5.2 controller/methods not found until rename controller. Anyone have any idea why?

Tags: exception, controller, laravel-5, composer-php

Hi & many thanks in advance.

I was demoing a new project for a client (written in Laravel 5.2) yesterday, when it - very embarrassingly - fell over with a method not found in controller error. Clicking another link to the same controller resulted in a controller not found error. The annoying thing is, this particular controller, it's namespacing & routes have been working perfectly for weeks, since the last time I touched them.

Out of desperation (& in front of the client!), having cleared the app cache, route cache, triple checked namespaces etc, I renamed the controller, & its class name to something silly (so it wouldn't clash with anything), updated its related routes & Bingo!  everything sprang to life again!

Although every thing is fine now, it's bothering the crap out of me why this happened.

The only thing I can think of was that Laravel's autoloader got screwed after I installed an imaging package to it under composer the other day, but im fairly new to Laravel so could be completely barking up the wrong tree!

Anybody, encounter something like this, or have any idea what could have gone wrong? Or perhaps someone could kindly help point me in the right direction so I might have a chance of figuring this out?

Any assistance will be very gratefully received!
Cheers, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah i think you are right that the autoloader must have got screwed up somehow. It does happen every now and again to me where some class cant be found. The simple solution is (if the class had previously been working) to re-compile the auto load file. You can do this easily and quickly in composer:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Cheers, for this, mate. Ill give it a go.